# How to Redirect unlimited number of urls or iframes with a time gap in between all of them

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Basically I am trying to find a way where I can redirect videos on swagbucks automatically without having to click on them manually each time within a 30 second time period. 
So I've been researching on how to redirect any number of urls or iframes that I want and display them one at a time with a time gap in between all of them. I was able to find an example that redirects 2 set of iframes but when I try to redirect 3 or more it displays them together. Here is what I tried:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://globalvideo.swagbucks.com/video/persia-whiteif-people-knew/289/64423"); 
exit();
?>

<script language="JavaScript">
var time = null
function move() {
myiframe.location.href = 'http://globalvideo.swagbucks.com/video/blue-ruin/185/415878'; 
}
</script>

<body onload="timer=setTimeout('move()',5000)">
<iframe id="myiframe" name="myiframe" src=" http://globalvideo.swagbucks.com/video/persia-whiteif-people-knew/289/64423"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was kind of hard to rework your code since you didn't give us a Fiddle.

Anyway I wrote down a fiddle that I'm sure you could use.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shaharlini/t4t6F/)**

I'm using jQuery, which I suggest you to use:

This is the main function :

```
 setInterval(function(){
   i+=1;
      if(i>2){
     i=0;
     }
    $("iframe").attr("src", links[i]);

}, 3000);
```